Confusion in proof about characterization of quasi-coherent module
I am reading the Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, proof of theorem 7.16 and I'm a bit confused about some of the statement.
Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a locally ringed space and let $f\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a global section. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Then the image of $f$ under the restriction homomorphim $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X) \to \Gamma(X_f, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is invertible so  there exists an induced homomorphism of $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$-modules $$\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})_f \to \Gamma(X_f,\mathcal{F}) \tag{7.10.1}$$, where the left hand side is the localization of the $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$-module $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})$ by $f$. We accept this fact.
I am trying to understand next statement ( Gortz's book Theorem 7.16 )

Theorem 7.16 ( (iii) $\Rightarrow$ (iv) ) . Let $X$ be a scheme and let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Then next are equivalent.

(iii) if $\mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent
(iv) For every open affine subset $U=\operatorname{Spec}A$ of $X$ and every $f\in A$ the homomorphism $(7.10.1)$
$$\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})_f \to \Gamma(D(f),\mathcal{F}) $$
is an isomorphism.


Sketch of Proof. ( (iii) $\Rightarrow$ (iv) ) :  We can assume that $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$ is affine and that $U=X$. Then the author shows that there exist finitely many $g_i \in A$ such that $X=\bigcup_i D(g_i)$ and such that $\mathcal{F}|_{D(g_i)}$, $\mathcal{F}|_{D(g_i)\cap D(g_j)}=\mathcal{F}|_{D(g_ig_j)}$ satisfies the condition (iv) above. We accept this argument. Let us denote the image of $f\in A_{g_i}$, and in $A_{g_ig_j}$ again by $f$. As $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf, we have a commutative diagram with exact rows
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})_f @>>> \prod_{i}\Gamma(D(g_i),\mathcal{F})_f@>>> \prod_{i,j}\Gamma(D(g_ig_j),\mathcal{F})_f  \\
@VVV @V\alpha VV @V \alpha' VV @V \alpha'' VV \\
0 @>>> \Gamma(D(f),\mathcal{F}) @>>> \prod_{i}\Gamma(D(fg_i),\mathcal{F}) @>>> \prod_{i,j}\Gamma(D(fg_ig_j),\mathcal{F})
\end{CD}
$$
Here the upper row is obtained by localizing the exact sequence
$$ 0 \to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{F}) \to \prod_{i}\Gamma(D(g_i),\mathcal{F}) \to \prod_{i,j} \Gamma(D(g_ig_j),\mathcal{F})$$
, and we use that localization commutes with finite prodcuts. As we have seen, $\alpha'$ and $\alpha''$ are isomorphisms, hence $\alpha$ is an isomorphism by the Five Lemma. QED.
I am little confused about the bold statement. I think "Localization commutes with finite products" means :

If $M_1, \ldots, M_n$ are $A$-modules, then there exists an isomorphism (of $A$-modules, and of $S^{-1}A$-modules) $S^{-1}(M_1 \times \cdots \times M_n) \to S^{-1}M_1 \times \cdots\times S^{-1}M_n$.

Then in our situation, for example for $\prod_{i}\Gamma(D(g_i),\mathcal{F})$ term,
what does it mean to take localization for some multiplicative set S? What is the multiplicative set corresponding to S? My first guess is, since $\mathcal{F}$ is an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, each $\Gamma(D(g_i),\mathcal{F})$ has structure of $\Gamma(D(g_i),\mathcal{O}_X)=  A_{g_i}$-module. Upto the algebra morphism $A\to A_{g_i}$, we can view $\Gamma(D(g_i),\mathcal{F})$ as $A$-module. So we can view $\prod_{i}\Gamma(D(g_i),\mathcal{F})$ as $A$-module. Then we may localize $\prod_{i}\Gamma(D(g_i),\mathcal{F})$ by $f\in A$. Is this the author's intention? Furthermore,
$(\prod_{i}\Gamma(D(g_i),\mathcal{F}))_f \cong \prod_{i}(\Gamma(D(g_i),\mathcal{F}))_f \stackrel{\text{?}}{=} \prod_{i}(\Gamma(D(g_i),\mathcal{F}))_{f_i}$, where $f_i$ is the image of $f$ in $A_{g_i}$ as in the proof, so that we can deduce that $\alpha'$ ( simliarly $\alpha''$ ) is an isomorphism? Can anyone resolve this confution?

OP please, once again, the way you write your questions makes them completely unreadable. It is not necessary to write long paragraphs about every single thing in algebraic geometry.

That is just one opinion. I can read the question without effort.

@CraniumClamp : O.K. I will try to improve. ( P.s. What improvements would be good ? )

What you have understood as in your last paragraph is correct, and that is the obvious, natural, canonical convention.

O.K. I got it. Everyone thank you very much !
